# nginx /login vs /login/ route

Tags: nginx

Right now in my nginx config, I have the following rule

```
location /login/ {
      deny all; 
}
```

I just got notified that someone tried to hit `/login` (our login route is different from straight `/login`)

Should the `location` be `/login` rather than `/login/`? Is my current `location` route incorrect?

Comment: No. `/login` is not the same as `/login/` It's not true in the address bar of the browser  either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You describe the workflow, without describing any requirements.

***What are your requirements?  Your configuration can only be correct or incorrect given the requirements.***

---

If your requirement is to deny requests with a prefix of `/login/`, leaving all other requests like `/login`, `/login.php`, `/login-…` et al alone, then your configuration is 100% correct.

---

If your requirement is to deny all requests starting from `/login`, then you must remove the trailing slash from your location specification, resulting in:

```
location /login {
    deny all;
}
```

---

Additionally, if you have a `.php` handler, usually implemented through a regex-based location, which normally take precedence over prefix-based locations, then you might also want to make your `/login` `location` to have a higher precedence than the regex-based locations, with the help of the `^~` modifier, like so:

```
location ^~ /login {
    deny all;
}
```

---

For more details, you can refer to the official documentation of these directives:

- http://nginx.org/r/location
- http://nginx.org/r/deny

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**;

`/login` is not equal to `/login/`.

**More details:**

Location block usually take the next form:

```
location optional_modifier location_match
```

In your case no modifiers are present so the location is interpreted as a prefix match. Therefore, `/login` is not equal to `/login/`.

If you have specific path for the login you can use equal sign as the optional_modifier so this block will be considered a match if the request URI exactly matches the location given.

Another option is to use this location which will be interpreted as a case-sensitive regular expression match. you can do something like that

```
location ~ /login/(sub_path_1|sub_path_2) {
      deny all; 
}
```

I would really recommend on reading the *Matching Location Blocks* in the [Understanding Nginx Server and Location Block Selection Algorithms](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms) or the nginx beginners guide as @Pruthvi Kumar advised above.

Answer (score 0):

`/login` is not equal to `/login/`. What you may need is something like this:

```
location ~ /login {
    deny all;
}
```

You can use regular expressions to block all routes matching a certain pattern

More details here - http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html